# Apply Stylish to all websites but NOT browser

Tags: css, firefox, stylish, firefox-nightly

I want to apply a Stylish theme to all inpux boxes, textareas and select boxes, so I wrote:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
textarea, input, select {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

My understanding is that that will only apply to Web pages, but it's also affecting the URL bar, turning it white. Is there a way to make it not affect the URL bar?

I'm using Firefox Nightly (version 43).

### Update

If you want GTK3 Firefox to look right with a dark theme, the final solution is a stylish config with:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document url-prefix('http://'), url-prefix('https://') {
  textarea, input, select {
    background-color: white !important;
    color: black !important;
  }
}
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox uses mix of XUL and HTML for its chrome, so declaring default CSS namespace affects HTML elements from browser chrome as well. You can wrap your style in `@-moz-document` block restricting origin of target content, like:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix('http://'), url-prefix('https://') { /* your code here */}
```